# How to add the sum of several squares (bourne scripting)

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to write a script that takes a list of integers as command line arguments, calculates the square of each integer, then gives me the sum of the squares. Here's what I have so far...

```
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 integer-list"
    exit 1
fi

for list in "$@"
do
    echo "The square of $list is: $(($list*$list))" 
done
```

As you can see, I have a simple for loop to deal with the squares, I'm just not sure how to get the sum of those squares and echo that to the screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a sum of previous squares to current square of item from the list.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 integer-list"
    exit 1
fi

SUM=0
for ITEM in "$@"
do
  SUM=$(($SUM+$ITEM*$ITEM))
done

echo "Sum of squares is :" $SUM
```

Comment: Just a minor point: Maybe the first line should be `#!/bin/sh` because the OP doesn't want it as _bash_, but as Bourne shell script.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line -

```
$: for n in 2 3 4
> do q=$((n*n))
>    echo "square of $n is $q"
>    s=$((s+q))
> done; echo "Sum of squares: $s"
square of 2 is 4
square of 3 is 9
square of 4 is 16
Sum of squares: 29
```

In a script, you can just say

```
for n in "$@"
```